# Optimizing and finding maximum value within Pandas Df by combining values of rows

Tags: pandas, scipy

I have the following `df`:

```
level   type  price1    price2
5250    A   0.233   0.2865
5250    B   0.004   0.006
5500    A   0.197   0.2545
5500    B   0.0055  0.0075
5750    A   0.1615  0.223
5750    B   0.0075  0.009
6000    A   0.127   0.1925
6000    B   0.0105  0.0125
6250    A   0.1215  0.1635
6250    B   0.0135  0.0165
6500    A   0.099   0.136
6500    B   0.021   0.024
6750    A   0.071   0.085
6750    B   0.03    0.0325
7000    A   0.052   0.0555
7000    B   0.044   0.047
7250    A   0.036   0.0395
7250    B   0.063   0.0675
7500    A   0.024   0.0275
7500    B   0.086   0.091
7750    A   0.0165  0.019
7750    B   0.111   0.161
8000    A   0.0105  0.0135
8000    B   0.118   0.1915
8250    A   0.0085  0.0105
8250    B   0.137   0.224
8500    A   0.0055  0.008
8500    B   0.1835  0.257
8750    A   0.0045  0.0065
8750    B   0.2035  0.291
9000    A   0.0035  0.0055
9000    B   0.002   1.956
```

I divide the `df` into `df_A` and `df_B` based on the column `type`.
Next, I want to find the levels/rows which combined maximizes the following:

```
sum = buy_A + buy_B - sell_A - sell_B
```

where

```
buy_A = df_A.loc[row, 'price2']
buy_B = df_B.loc[row, 'price2']
sell_A = df_A.loc[row, 'price1']
sell_B = df_B.loc[row, 'price1']
```

I use here `row` for clarity, but in my script `row` should be equal to a value of column `level`. I have a constraint. For `buy_A` and `sell_B` the `level` should be equal and for `sell_A` and `buy_B` the value of `level` should be equal. Including this results in:

```
buy_A = float(df_A.loc[(df_A['level'] == level_1), 'price2'])
buy_B = float(df_B.loc[(df_B['level'] == level_2), 'price2'])
sell_A = float(df_A.loc[(df_A['level'] == level_1), 'price1'])
sell_B = float(df_B.loc[(df_B['level'] == level_2), 'price1'])
```

Basically, for the above `df` I get the following matrix:

[image]

I would like to return the value of the max value within the matrix and the corresponding levels.

My script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def obj(x, df):
   df_A = df.loc[(df['type'] == 'A')]
   df_B = df.loc[(df['type'] == 'B')]
   sum = df_A['price1'] + df_B['price1'] - df_A['price2'] - df_B['price2']
   return -1 * sum


if __name__ == "__main__":
   df = pd.read_csv('quotes.csv')
   guess = 0
   solver = minimize(obj, args=(df), x0=guess, method='Nelder-Mead', options={'disp': True})
```

What do I need to change to get the max value and the corresponding levels? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `df_B.loc[row, 'price2']` equal to both `buy_B` and `sell_B`? Is that a typo?

Comment: yes sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sum` is a built-in function in Python, I'd like to replace that with `z`. And since you have constraint on `level` being identical in (`buy_A`, `sell_B`), as well as (`sell_A`, `buy_B`), let's rearrange your equation to make this clearer:

```
z = buy_A + buy_B - sell_A - sell_B 
  = (buy_A - sell_B) + (buy_B - sell_A)
  = x + y
```

---

Let's dive into your question. The first thing we do is to reformat the original dataframe to line up the levels:

```
tmp = df.rename({'price1': 'sell', 'price2': 'buy'}, axis=1) \
        .set_index(['level', 'type']) \
        .unstack()

# tmp:
         sell             buy        
type        A       B       A       B
level                                
5250   0.2330  0.0040  0.2865  0.0060
5500   0.1970  0.0055  0.2545  0.0075
5750   0.1615  0.0075  0.2230  0.0090
6000   0.1270  0.0105  0.1925  0.0125
6250   0.1215  0.0135  0.1635  0.0165
```

Then calculating our `x` and `y`:

```
x = tmp[('buy', 'A')] - tmp[('sell', 'B')]
y = tmp[('buy', 'B')] - tmp[('sell', 'A')]
```

Next, we need to calculate `z`. `z` isn't simply `x` + `y`, but every value in `x` added to every value in `y`; hence `z` is a square matrix. But we don't want the whole matrix either. We only want the triangle below the main diagonal line. The `numpy.ma` module provides functions on masked arrays, where we can mark certain elements as if they do not exist.

```
import numpy.ma as ma

# Mask away the upper triangle, including the main diagonal
# len(x) == len(y)
mask = np.triu(np.ones((len(x), len(y))))

# Use numpy broadcasting to add every value in `x` to every value in `y`
# `x` and `y` are pandas Series. `.values` get the underlying numpy array
#
# `y.values[:, None]` raises `y` to another dimension. This is what
# triggers numpy's array broadcasting and make `z` a square matrix
z = -ma.array(x.values + y.values[:, None], mask=mask)

# If you want to visualize `z`, type this into the debugger
# pd.DataFrame(z, index=tmp.index, columns=tmp.index)
```

The final step is to get the levels that produces the max value when added together. If there are multiple cells with the max value, this will only get the first one:

```
i,j = np.unravel_index(z.argmax(), z.shape)

# The level with the max sum
level1, level2 = tmp.index[[i,j]]   # 7250, 7000

# The max value of the sums
z[i,j]                              # -0.043
```